# Turning Text into Layer in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, layers, text

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

Can I turn the text boxes which I have inserted on my map into a layer which keeps the same aspect ratio with the map?

Answer (score 2):

This works with labels of features

1. Right click on layer in table of content and convert to annotations in file geodatabase
2. Use feature outline mask with mask kind = exact to convert annotations to polygons

Comment: Thank you. How do I get started doing that?